# Were 3/5 of the people involved in the Cliven Bundy "Oregon Standoff" government informants?

Tags: united-states

I'm reading about how the people involved in the "[Oregon Standoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupation_of_the_Malheur_National_Wildlife_Refuge)" in early 2016 were all fully acquitted

[One Reddit comment thread](http://reddit.h0.re/post/59r76a/Oregon_standoff:_All_defendants_found_not_guilty) discusses the allegation that the reason for the acquittal was that such a large portion of those involved were actually government informants:

> **[–]welfarecuban 601 points:** I don't think this was really about "nullification." From my observing
>   of this case over the past few weeks, it started to take a turn once
>   all the information about government informers started coming out.
>   They ended up looking like agents-provacateur, and that more than
>   anything else probably caused the jury to doubt the whole of the
>   government's "narrative" in this case. Since many of the crimes in the
>   indictment rely upon "intent," these informants had a distorting
>   effect upon establishing the real intent of the individuals on trial.
>   And in a system that asks jurors to look for evidence "beyond a
>   reasonable doubt," it was just too much.
>
> **[–]jeffhsu3 381 points:** Exactly, there were 15
>   federal informants (only 9 were with the group on federal property in
>   January). One of the informants ran the gun range and provided combat
>   training. When the number of informants doubles the number of
>   defendants, it's hard to distinguish intent from entrapment.
>
> **[–]rkoloeg 63 points:** Germany recently had a problem with this in their 
>   attempts
>   to prosecute right-wing extremists. It turned out that right-wing
>   groups were so thoroughly infiltrated by the security services, that
>   it was nearly impossible to distinguish whether any criminal
>   activities were carried out by actual right-wingers without being
>   influenced by their supposed leaders.

A comment later goes on to claim 3/5 of those involved were informants. Is this accurate? What fraction of the people involved in this were government informants?

Comment: Is a commenter in this thread notable? Can we find a better claimant?

Comment: Where's the 3/5th comment? I can't see it in the link I added, but that doesn't seem to be the original.

Comment: Note that the middle comment in the quote asserts that there 15 informants, 9 of whom were involved in the occupation. That's 3/5 -- so the exact wording of the claim is important. This may just be a matter of someone misreading or misrepresenting the original claim. Not 3/5 of those involved were informants; 3/5 of the informants were involved. And the Wikipedia link says that there were over two dozen people charged.  3/5 of 25 (the smallest integer larger than 24) would be 15.  So just doing the math from the cited sources puts the claim at untrue.  9 of 25 is less than 3/5, as is 15 of 31.

Comment: Closed while we sort out if  @Brythan's speculation is correct: that the title is  simple misreading of the claim.

Comment: @Brythan how many were actually at the refugee? It was only 4 at the end, but how many originally?  This article says "the number of militia members in the Malheur National Wildlife Refuge headquarters is likely between six and 12 people" http://www.wweek.com/2016/01/02/militia-group-takes-over-federal-building-in-eastern-oregon-because-the-lord-was-not-pleased/

Comment: @Oddthinking feel free to edit the question however you see fit, I'm ok with whatever. Im away from home atm, wont have a chance to sort it out this weekend.